# Extracting a variable in a lambda or struct with overloaded operator()

Tags: c++, function, pointers, lambda, function-pointers

This is a bit of a doozy and needs some explanation. I'm sorry in advance if I mess up the semantics or if I misunderstand something- I'm no beginner to C++ but some of its more advanced features I have yet to fully wrap my head around.

I'm writing language bindings from a library in C++ (although I am using the C API for this library since it's compiled with MSVC and I'm using MinGW) and I need to write up a binding for callbacks using function pointers. Even if I was using the C++ API, this would be a problem.

Luckily for me, the language I am writing bindings for Ruby (it doesn't really matter, I'm pretty sure other languages have similar C API bindings and this is language agnostic anyway) allows me to get an anonymous function useful for callbacks, in the form of a `VALUE`.

It's easy enough for me to wrap up these callbacks in a lambda which I can get a function pointer to, like so:

```cpp
/* This is just a function that is bound to Ruby. It doesn't really matter much. */
VALUE set_some_callback(VALUE callback)
{
   /* The types here don't really matter */
   /* Create the lambda */
   auto lambda = [callback](){
      /* Run the callback, the semantics don't matter a lot here */
      rb_funcall(callback, rb_intern("call"), 0);
   }
   /* Takes a function pointer (something like (void*)()) */
   library_set_some_callback(fn); 
   return Qnil; // Return nil 
}
```

This works just fine, in fact I've written bindings for other libraries that do something like this. However, this *won't* work for the particular library I'm writing bindings for since it exposes callbacks you've set in a struct.

```cpp
/* Again, semantics don't matter here, this is for sake of example */
typedef struct Foo
{
  int data;
  (void*)() callback;
} Foo;
```

This is where the problem lies.

I can bind `data` (or whatever equivalent) just fine, but I can't bind the callback since it's a function pointer wrapping the actual callback. To bind the callback, I'd somehow need to extract that, and I don't know how...

I've come up with something along the lines of overloading `operator()` in a custom struct to wrap a callback, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach, or if it would even work.

```cpp
struct BoundCallback
{
  /* Store the callback */
  VALUE callback;

  /* Overload () */
  void operator() const
  {
    rb_funcall(callback, rb_intern("call"), 0);
  }
};

VALUE get_callback_from_foo(VALUE self)
{
  /* Implementation of this doesn't matter. */
  Foo foo = get_data_from(self);

  /* Would this work...? */
  BoundCallback callback = static_cast<BoundCallback>(foo.callback);

  /* Would this work too? */
  return callback.callback;
}
```

What's the best way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Does the exposed C structure (with the function-pointer) have any kind of user-data pointer? If it has, you could use a simple callback which casts the user-data pointer into an object and calls a function on that object passing whatever arguments might be needed from the structure itself (assuming that the structure is passed to the original callback).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I didn't think of that, actually.
The structs do have a `void*` for user data luckily that get passed in to callbacks, but unfortunately some of these structs have multiple callbacks, so I'm unsure how that would scale.

Comment: What does ‘exposes callbacks you've set in a struct’ mean?

Comment: Callbacks in the library are set by passing a function pointer into a function, and those callback function pointers are exposed in various different structs in the library as a struct member (I sorta made an example with the `Foo` struct in my post)
If you want, I can edit my post with a more in depth example